# Multiple JS Popups On Same Page

Tags: javascript, function, popup, popupwindow

I have a popup javascript I am using on one of my html pages.

It works fine, but... when I tried to add a second one in a different location, the script would not function.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

I need at least three of these on one webpage in different locations.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Here is the basic script....

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    <script>function myfunction() {var popup1 = document.getElementById("popup1"); popup1.classList.toggle("showpopup1");}</script>

    <style>

    body {margin:0;}

    /* popup container */
    .popup1 {
        margin-left:200px; 
        margin-top:200px; 
        margin-bottom:0px; 
        position:relative; 
        display:inline-block; 
        cursor:pointer; 
        -webkit-user-select:none; 
        -moz-user-select:none; 
        -ms-user-select:none; 
        user-select:none;
    }

    /* The actual popup */
    .popup1 .popup1text {
        visibility:hidden; 
        background-color:#555; 
        color:#fff; 
        border-radius:10px; 
        padding:8px 8px 8px 8px; 
        width:400px; 
        height:80px; 
        position:absolute; 
        text-align:left; 
        z-index:1; 
        bottom:130%; 
        left:50%; 
        margin-left:-210px;
    }

    /* Popup arrow */
    .popup1 .popup1text::after {
        content:""; 
        position:absolute; 
        top:100%; 
        left:50%; 
        margin-left:-5px; 
        border-width:5px; 
        border-style:solid; 
        border-color:#555 transparent transparent transparent;
    }

    /* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
    .popup1 .showpopup1 {
        visibility:visible; 
        -webkit-animation:fadeIn 1s; 
        animation:fadeIn 1s;
    }

    /* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
    @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn{from {opacity: 0;} to {opacity: 1;}
    @keyframes fadeIn{from {opacity: 0;} to {opacity:1 ;}

    </style>

    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="popup1" onclick="myfunction()">POPUP 1<span class="popup1text" id="popup1">Popup 1 Text</span></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your code only has one popup so we can't reproduce the problem you are describing.  But if you use `document.getElementById("popup1")` in your script then yes, that will only work once.

Comment: I understand the other elements must have different ID's. Tried that and a whole bunch of other changing of 'names', ID's, and 'functions'. still no luck. And yes... I realize I only included one popup. I did that on purpose instead of including failed clutter.

Comment: You need to post what *doesn't* work.  There are a million different ways you could be adding a second popup, and we need to know how you are doing it.

Comment: I removed the java tag; I saw nothing java related and javascript != java.

Comment: Paul... if there are millions of ways, based on the code i posted, can you give me an example of one of the million? As the dozen or so I attempted failed. Thanks.

Comment: https://codepen.io/pjabbott/pen/qjaBwv

Comment: Paul... That was a huge help. Saves my day. Appreciated. Thank you. :)

Comment: ChiefTwo"Pencil... I guess you miss the script in the code. All good. ;)